# State Change Isn't Saving in React and Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose

I cannot get my checkbox state to change. The default option in my Mongoose model is false. I can successfully get it to update the user's profile when they check it and submit only on the first time (it'll change to true), but when they go back to edit the profile (same routes) and $set the profile fields, it doesn't change the boolean value of the "displayEmailOnProfile" to false. It just remains checked. The console.logs() are kinda weird as well. When the box is checked, it prints out true and then the state for displayEmailOnProfile is false. When it's unchecked, the state for displayEmailOnProfile is true?

Then when I hit submit, it's not updating anything on the mongoose model?

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        displayEmailOnProfile: false,
        errors: {}
    }
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.onCheck = this.onCheck.bind(this);
}
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        // Set component fields state
        this.setState({
            displayEmailOnProfile: profile.displayEmailOnProfile,
        });
    }
}

onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
}

onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const profileData = {
        displayEmailOnProfile: this.state.displayEmailOnProfile
    }

    this.props.createProfile(profileData, this.props.history);
}

onCheck = (e) => {
    console.log(this.state);
    console.log(e.currentTarget.checked);

    this.setState({
        displayEmailOnProfile: e.currentTarget.checked
    });
}
```

And here is the HTML / React markup

```
<div className="form-check mb-4">                 
    <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox"  id="defaultCheck1" name="displayEmailOnProfile" checked={this.state.displayEmailOnProfile} onChange={this.onCheck}></input>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="customCheck1">Display Email On Profile</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is completely correct and `console.log` is printing the right thing. You are doing `console.log` inside the `onCheck` method — which is printing the current value.

What happens is, when you do `set state`, life cycle methods are called asynchronously which update the component and set the state. So, if you do `console.log` of your state right after setting the state (which is synchronous), it will print the previous state, because it is not yet updated.

Following are the lifecycle methods which are called:

1. `shouldComponentUpdate`
2. `componentWillUpdate`
3. `componentDidUpdate`

So, if you want to check if the value was updated or not, you should do `console.log` inside `componentDidUpdate`. It will tell you your updated state.

In order to explain the working, I have created a short demo for you on [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-rgb-nyv0b?fontsize=14) with your code sample. Which explains the working and shows that your code is correct.

Now, as far as it is concerned that Mongoose is not updating the values, I can't say anything without looking at your code. You must be having some mistakes in the code for updating the values. I'm not sure, but cross check if you are using the same page for updating as for `submit` make sure, you change the request from `post` to `put` and check for how to update values using Mongoose.